# Circle with three different border colors

Tags: css, svg, border, css-shapes

I have this CSS for a circle with one border color:

```css
.circle {
  border: 6px solid #ffd511;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 12px 6px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">17</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image: circle with one border color]

How should I change the CSS to have **three border colors** - as on the clock:

- from 0 to 4 color #1
- from 4 to 8 color #2
- from 8 to 12 color #3

I am sure, its possible, with element `<canvas>`, but I am not successful with doing that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143736/css-circle-border-with-various-colors  Here you can find the answer

Comment: Once a question has answers you shouldn't change it in such a way as to make those answers look incomplete or invalid. Ask another question if you need to. I've rolled back the question to the point that the answers were added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve a **circle border divided into 3 sections** with an [inline svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) using:

- a [circle element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle)
- and the [stroke-dasharray attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) to make the sections

Here is an example:

```css
svg{width:30%;height:auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 10">
  <defs>
    <circle id="circle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0.5" fill="transparent" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#circle" stroke="pink" stroke-dasharray="0,2.09,8.38,30" />
  <use xlink:href="#circle" stroke="green" stroke-dasharray="0,10.47,8.38,30" />
  <use xlink:href="#circle" stroke="orange" stroke-dasharray="2.09,16.75,6.3" />
</svg>
```

### Edit

To add text inside the circle, you can use the [svg text element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text):

```css
svg{width:30%;height:auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 10">
  <defs>
    <circle id="circle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0.5" fill="transparent" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#circle" stroke="pink" stroke-dasharray="0,2.09,8.38,30" />
  <use xlink:href="#circle" stroke="green" stroke-dasharray="0,10.47,8.38,30" />
  <use xlink:href="#circle" stroke="orange" stroke-dasharray="2.09,16.75,6.3" />
  <text x="5" y="6.5" text-anchor="middle" font-size="5">17</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, just one more question, how can I have inside some text, like you can see in my edited question?

Comment: I am trying to implement your code, but I am unable; the circle element is a marker shown in Google Maps API v3.

Answer (score 7):

Try this with css [Pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)  three different border colors(same length)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: skyblue;
  transition: background 0.6s ease
}
body:hover {
  background: #CBE0E8
}
div {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 0px #484848, 0 0 6px 0px #484848;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 10px solid green;
  border-right: 10px solid red;
  border-bottom: 10px solid red;
  border-left: 10px solid green;
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  position: relative
}
div:before, div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div:before {
  border-top: 10px solid yellow;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(60deg)
}
div:after {
  border-top: 10px solid yellow;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(30deg)
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is also the solution.