# Circle marker with three different border colors in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-markers

I have this CSS for a circle with one border color:

```js
m = new MarkerWithLabel({
  position: pos,
  map: map,
  labelContent: txt,
  labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(18, 18),
  labelClass: "circle",
  icon: "/i/t.png"
});
```

```css
.circle {
  border: 6px solid #ffd511;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 12px 6px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">17</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image: circle with one border color]

How should I change the CSS to have **three border colors** - as on the clock:

- from 0 to 4 color #1
- from 4 to 8 color #2
- from 8 to 12 color #3

As in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37207073/1631551) of my previous question:

```css
svg{width:30%;height:auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 10 10">
  <defs>
    <circle id="circle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke-width="0.5" fill="transparent" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#circle" stroke="pink" stroke-dasharray="0,2.09,8.38,30" />
  <use xlink:href="#circle" stroke="green" stroke-dasharray="0,10.47,8.38,30" />
  <use xlink:href="#circle" stroke="orange" stroke-dasharray="2.09,16.75,6.3" />
</svg>
```

Required

[image]

The circle element is a marker shown in Google Maps API v3, so I am unable to use SVG.

Also another solution is to use an image:

```
.circle {
  background: url('circle.png') no-repeat;
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Give it a [GO](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-arcs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is solution to do it with CSS as Marker for Google Maps API.

So I managed to create an image, and use this as background for Marker class `.circle`:

```
.circle {
  background: url('circle.png') no-repeat;
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[image: three colors border]

Answer (score 0):

You  could do use of canvas, something like this will do it:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="250"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var context2 = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var context3 = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var x = canvas.width / 2;
  var y = canvas.height / 2;
  var radius = 75;
  var startAngle = 1.5 * Math.PI;
  var endAngle = 0.15 * Math.PI;
  var counterClockwise = false;

  //1st arc
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
  context.lineWidth = 10;

  // line color
  context.strokeStyle = '#FFA325';
  context.stroke();

  //second arc
  startAngle=endAngle;
  endAngle=0.85 * Math.PI;
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);


  // line color
  context.strokeStyle = '#FFBEC9';
  context.stroke();

  //third arc
  startAngle=endAngle;
  endAngle=1.5 * Math.PI;
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);


  // line color
  context.strokeStyle = '#007F1B';
  context.stroke();
</script>
```

Hope it helps ,[HERE](http://codepen.io/T04435/pen/aZdYoE) you can find a link to a codepen, Thanks